# Can I safely use the eval() function to change values of some variables which names are stored in an array

Tags: javascript, variables, eval

I want to change the values from a lot of variables.

At first I used this option:

```
date = [];
temp = [];
temp_min = [];
temp_max = [];
humidity = [];
... and so on.
```

And later I found out that I can use the the eval() function to make the process a little bit easier and fancier.

```
const FIELDS = ['date', 'temp', 'temp_min', 'temp_max', 'humidity'];
for (let j = 0; j < FIELDS.length; j++) {
    eval(FIELDS[j] + " = [];");
}
```

I wanted to learn more about this function and stumbled upon this site:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval

On the very top there is explained that the use of this function is very dangerous when used wrongly
[image]

And now I wanted to know whether this function is (enough) secure in my case.

Comment: Are the variables already arrays before you try to empty them?

Comment: Yes, but I declare them also using eval()

Comment: Why do you want to dynamically generate variables like this, how are these variables to be used and for what purpose? Sounds like an xy problem

Comment: I use them to later display a chart with the chart.js library, because I found out that I can't use a two-dimensional Array, so I have to use a lot of one-dimensional Arrays.

Comment: Generally, feeling the need to use `eval()` like this means that you have made a very large mistake in designing your code. If you need lots of arrays that are related in purpose, declare a single object and make each array a property of the object. Then you can use simple property references to dynamically locate the arrays.

Comment: @Pointy (Sorry I deleted my comment when I saw yours that said basically the same thing.) I suggested `window` only as an emergency, say, because the library demands that the arrays be global.

Comment: @RaymondChen yes I understand completely. As I get older and more crotchety I've decided to start telling people directly to stop trying to do bad things :)

Comment: "*I found out that I can't use a two-dimensional Array, so I have to use a lot of one-dimensional Arrays*" - I really doubt that. You might better [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) specifically about that chart.js problem

Comment: if you are the authority of naming those variables, then yes. it is safe to use `eval`

Comment: @ITgoldman it may be "safe" but that does not make it a good idea. For example, generally the use of `eval()` in a function will make the optimizer ignore it for just-in-time optimization. There's really no reason for it in this case.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm to summarize the comments:

1. don't use `eval`
2. if you must, use this function which leaves you with a graceful way out of this cunnudrum.

```js
function define_arr(name, context) {
  context = context || window
  context[name] = []
}

'humidity,wind,saturation,co2,alert'.split(',').map(define_arr)
console.log(humidity)
```